# How to split a string value?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string value, that I want to store in a two separate string variables. How can I perform this. I tried with Split methods but I couldnt.

```
String value="07:00"; I want,
String first=07;
String Second=00;
```

How can I perform it??

Comment: "*I tried with Split methods but I couldnt*" - why couldn't you? What about string.Split does not satisfy your challenge?

Comment: try value.Split(':')

Comment: just split according to `:` symbol.

Comment: [How to: Split Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

Comment: It's a basic question. Do a search before asking.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, I know  how to split a string but I am not aware about how to save this splitted values in a separate string variables. That why I asked here. Is it wrong???

Comment: @SaraJohn All `Split` overloads returns a string array. You can get splited values like `array[0]`, `array[1]` etc.. Please read the documentation of that method.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, Thank you I did not think that much..

Answer (score 4):

How about just using [`string.Split(char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
string value="07:00";
string[] split = value.Split(':');
string first = split[0];
string second = split[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach since i assume that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the string is  actually a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
TimeSpan span;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse("07:00", out span))
    Console.WriteLine("Hours: {0} Minutes: {1}", span.Hours, span.Minutes); // Hours: 7 Minutes: 0
```

Comment: XY problem on OP's part, you think?

Comment: @J.Steen: yes, i think so.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] result = value.Split(':');

Console.WriteLine(result[0]); //will output 07
Console.WriteLine(result[1]); //will output 00
```